# How to round up in progress programming

Tags: rounding, progress-4gl

I am writing a report for an MRP program and it contains a field I calculate for the quantity to order.  I need to round the number up if it is a decimal point.

For example:  2.33 needs to be rounded up to 3 and so on.

I have tried

```
oder = round(order,0).
```

but that just get me 2.00
I need that number to be rounded up to the next whole number.

Comment: Maybe the `Ceiling` call as shown in [here](http://www.oehive.org/book/export/html/668) helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function roundUp returns integer ( x as decimal ):

  if x = truncate( x, 0 ) then
    return integer( x ).
   else
    return integer( truncate( x, 0 ) + 1 ).

end.

display roundUp( 2.33 ).
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = round(n + 0.4999999999, 0)
```

... should work for all for negative values of n too

- n = -2.0000001 ... x = -2
- n = -2.5 ... x = -2
- n = -2.9999999999 ... x = -2

roundUp() resolves to -1 in all the above negative values of n

Comment: This only works when you are limited to 10 digits to the right of the decimal.

Comment: The proper behavior of rounding functions with negative arguments is a subject of some debate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/rules-for-rounding-positive-and-negative-numbers

Answer (score 0):

This will work for negative values too. Return value is intentionally kept as Integer, you can keep it as Decimal too.

```
function roundUp returns integer 
( 
    input in-value as DECIMAL 
):

    def var x as decimal no-undo.
    def var y as decimal no-undo.

    if in-value < 0 then
    DO:
        x = truncate(in-value,0).     
        y =  in-value - x.      
        if abs(y) <= 0.5 then 
            return INTEGER(x).
        else 
            return INTEGER(round(in-value,0)).
    END.
    ELSE 
        return INTEGER(round(in-value,0)).

end function.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
DEF VAR X AS decimal.
DEF VAR Y AS integer.

update
x with frame a.

Y = X - 1.
display y.
IF (( X - Y ) < 0.5)
THEN do:
DISPLAY round(x,0) + 1.
end.
ELSE DO :
DISPLAY round(x,0).
end.
```