# Progress 4GL auto round off in case of decimal calculation

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am calculating this value in progress 31500 * (10 / 100) * (1 / 12) its giving 262.49999 but in scientific calculator of windows its giving 262.5... Why there is diffrence between these two values?

Comment: Please post code and version of Progress! I cannot reproduce: 

DISPLAY 31500 * (10 / 100) * (1 / 12).
DISPLAY 31500.0 * (10.0 / 100.0) * (1.0 / 12.0). Both gives 262.5.

Comment: MESSAGE does not round by default and shows the answer as 262.499999999...

Answer (score 4):

1 / 12 = 0.083333333333333333....

Preserving all precision the correct answer is 262.499999999999999...

(You could work it out by hand if you don't trust the computers.)

Which is why many calculations, especially those involving money, round numbers to a certain precision.

Rounding is not the same as truncation.  In a business context the 4gl ROUND( expression, precision ) function is usually what you want.

Occasionally you do actually need to TRUNCATE() -- but that is rare when dealing with money.  More frequent is a need for CEILING() (aka "round up") which, sadly, the 4GL does not provide.  Stackoverflow, however, has a solution to that ;)  [How to round up in progress programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584498/how-to-round-up-in-progress-programming)

I have lost count of the number of times I have seen homemade rounding code and had to explain why it doesn't do what the author expects. They used to teach this stuff in school but I guess they don't do that anymore?

There are other rounding rules that are used in scientific applications.  But since this is a progress-4gl tagged question I doubt that they are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your calculator is rounding up.  (Which is what @jensd's DISPLAY statement is doing. Try using MESSAGE.) It's also possible that your calculator is storing values to more than nine decimal places (which is what Openedge uses) or has a special rounding error protection algorithm (which Openedge does not).

Sometimes the problem is that ABL does integer arithmetic because the values in the expression are integers; but this does not appear to be the case here. This is just a calculation that does not come out cleanly in 9dp.